# Google Voice to Skype - Free?

Tags: skype, google-voice

Is there a way to forward a Google Voice number to a Skype number without an existing gizmo5 account (and they don't appear to be accepting more reservations post acquisition) for free?

Comment: Even with a gizmo5 acct skype linking is broken and when it worked calls were limited to something like 2-3 minutes. As a note of people who might find this in search. If you have a gizmo5 account, as of now you can softphone to the gizmo5 acct if you add the gizmo5 # into google voice.

Answer (score 1):

there is no **Free** way that I know of... you can if you have skype credits though

Comment: I was looking into the $2.99 a month plan here (http://buy.skype.com/paymonthly/?country=US#|recommendedSubscriptionsTab), but I'm not sure that handles it?